# detect if a message string is QP Encoded

Tags: c, unix, mime, quoted-printable

On FreeBsd system, i am trying to determine if an email message in the form of a c style string is qp encoded?

Is there a unix tool like iconv which can read in chunk of data and output the detected encoding? like charset detection?

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Really, you should get this information from the source of the data. Quoted-printable data should always be flagged as such. There's no 100% certain way to determine that data is QP since the key property of QP is that it's valid plain ASCII text. If the data contains a number of =XX sequences, and doesn't contain anything invalid in QP (like high bytes), then it's *probably* intended as QP, but that's about the best you can do.

Comment: The end of [Section 6.7 of RFC 2045](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6.7) lists forbidden strings, like an '=' not followed by two hexadecimal digits, lines longer than 76 characters, control characters other than TAB and CRLF.

Answer (score 0):

You look at the Content-Transfer-Encoding header field. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME for a starting point, including links to specifications.